# How to remove <int> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> in a table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to remove the following arguments that come in the table, which I attached:

```
<int> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
```

The table has been generated with the code.

```
library(questionr)
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

CrearSecuenciaAleatoria <- function(n) {
  sample(1:5, n, replace = T, prob = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.15, 0.15))
}

CrearTablaFrecuencia <- function(v){
  data.table(
    xi = unique(sort(v)),
    ni = as.numeric(table(v)),
    fi = as.numeric(prop.table(table(v))),
    Ni = cumsum(as.numeric(table(v))),
    Fi = cumsum(as.numeric(prop.table(table(v))))
  )
}

v <- CrearSecuenciaAleatoria(20)
dt <- CrearTablaFrecuencia(v)


print(dt, row.names = F)
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48165457/disable-pillar-formatting-for-tibble-printing

Comment: I cannot replicate this. Where are `{questionr}` and `{magrittr}` needed? Probably, you are creating a `tibble` somewhere? Potentially, a simple way out: `print(as.data.frame(dt), row.names = FALSE)`

Comment: However, based on https://pillar.r-lib.org/reference/pillar_options.html and https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/formatting.html, I don't see any obvious way to turn off the column type indicators (however, converting back to a data frame as @Friede suggests will definitely work)

Comment: @BenBolker or use `print.data.frame(dt)` since a tibble is already a data.frame.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the output at all, tibbles print `<dbl>`, not `<num>`.

Comment: print(as.data.frame(dt), row.names = FALSE) is sufficient. Above is the result.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include the answer.  If you want, you can answer your own question (you may have to wait a little while).

Comment: There is an experimental `num` type:  `tibble(x = num(1:3))`

Comment: Most of the comments seem to be confusing both row-names with column-class, and `data.table` with `tbl_df`. Am I mistaken, or is this solely about column-class headers on a `data.table`-class object? `pillar` has nothing to do with it afaict.

Answer (score 4):

You have a data.table and data.table v1.15.0 has enabled this in the `print` method by default. Refer to the documentation in `help("print.data.table")`.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x = 1:5, y = 11:15)
dt
#       x     y
#   <int> <int>
#1:     1    11
#2:     2    12
#3:     3    13
#4:     4    14
#5:     5    15

print(dt, class = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
# x  y
# 1 11
# 2 12
# 3 13
# 4 14
# 5 15
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to being able to modify it for each manual call to `print` (`print.data.table` when on a `data.table` object), we can control it via global options.

```r
data.table(a=1:2, b=pi + 0:1)
#    a        b
# 1: 1 3.141593
# 2: 2 4.141593
options(datatable.print.class=TRUE)
data.table(a=1:2, b=pi + 0:1)
#        a        b
#    <int>    <num>
# 1:     1 3.141593
# 2:     2 4.141593
```

This option was added in version 1.9.8 (released on CRAN in Nov 2016).